# What do these VBScript statements do?

Tags: vbscript

I don't know anyone that can read VBScript. I am wondering if anyone help me read the following statements?

```
Public Sub GetNodeName(CompIP)
    Dim i
    Dim ProcedureName
    ProcedureName = "GetNodeName(CompIP): " & CompIP
    ProcedureName = "ProcedureName & ": " & $Date & ": " & $Time

    For i = To $CompName -> Size
        If CompIP = $COMPUTER_IP[i] Then
            $NodeNumber = i
            $ComputerID = $CompName[i]
            i = $CompName -> Size + 1
            $DemoMode = 0
        Else 'Demomode
            $NodeNumber = 1
            $DemoMode = 1
            $ComputerID = "Demo Mode"
        End If
    Next
```

and

```
For i = 1 To $CompName -> Size
    If $CompName[i] = NodeName Then
        GetNodeNumber=i
        'Exit Loop
        i = $CompName -> Size + 1
    End if
Next

If GetNodeName = -1 Then $Trace("Node not found")
```

ComputerName is TABLET4. IP Address is 172.10.10.7.

Comment: VBScript has an `->` operator?

Comment: I don't know, that's how it's written. What do you think it means?

Comment: I don't know what the heck that is, but it's not vbscript.  `->` as a property accessor is valid in freebasic, but I can't find any variant of basic that allows `$` at the beginning of a variable name.

Comment: VBScript also doesn't use square brackets for index access. And there's a double quote missing in the second `ProcedureName = ...` statement.

Comment: Is that php? Perl? I presume you did not find this in a file with some sort of extension? If so, did you check what binary was associated with the file type for launch on that machine? Or search for the extension type online? Mutant stuff. Aspects of VBScript, PowerShell, Perl, php? I will add a couple of tags and see if we can reach someone who knows what they are talking about :-).

Comment: It's neither Perl nor PHP.

Comment: It's a section of a code that runs one of our 3rd-party proprietary software. The company that wrote the program is no longer in business and I'm trying to decipher sections of it. I thought it was written in VB. Being noob, I couldn't make it out, that's why I posted it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever language that is, the intent of the code is clear.

The sub iterates through parallel arrays `$CompName` and `$COMPUTER_IP` two find the name of the computer (`$CompName[i]`) that corresponds to the provided id (`CompIP`).

If a match is found, it sets `$NodeNumber` to the index of the match, `$ComputerID` to the name of the computer, and `$DemoMode` to `0`.

If no match is found, it sets `$NodeNumber` to `1`, `$ComputerID` to `Demo Mode`, and `$DemoMode` to `1`.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I apologize that it took me a very long time to come back to my post.